# Uniform/Pointwise Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

So, I have a somewhat arbitrary question about this topic but first I need to state the theorem I am familiar with and from which I will base my question.

---

**Theorem:** Let $(f_n)_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ functions. If:
$$f_n {\rightrightarrows f} \quad \text{and} \quad f_n ' {\rightrightarrows g}  $$

Then f is differentiable and also $f'=g$

---

Now with that in mind, my question is:

Supose I define $(f_n)_n$ and $f \enspace$in compact sets, as above, still with $f_n {\rightrightarrows f}$ , but this time $f_n $ are smooth functions;

Also, suppose I don't even know if $f_n'$ converges uniformly onto something.

**When/what hypothesis would be necessary** to ensure that $f_n'\to f'$?

where the single arrow denotes pointwise convergence.

Comment: What does $\underset{\mbox{n}}{\rightrightarrows}$ mean here?

Comment: The usual uniform convergence. Maybe it is best if I take the n off